# JQuery can't parse self-closed XML tags?

Tags: jquery, xml, parsing

here is a strange problem with JQuery. Apparently attempting to retrieve a value of an empty self-closing XML tag will not return an empty string as supposed, but the value of the next tag, with some trailing spaces. For instance I have this XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<results>
  <row>
    <id>3188</id>
    <account_id>840</account_id>
    <paid_to_date/>
    <nickname>Nick Name</nickname>
    <unit_code>013226005918194</unit_code>
    <time_stamp>2013-08-14 15:34:30.0</time_stamp>
    <time_zone>Europe/Budapest</time_zone>
    <sim_id>68</sim_id>
    <response_mode>1</response_mode>
    <response_email>johndoe@whatever.com</response_email>
    <response_phone/>
    <user_name>johndoe</user_name>
  </row>
</results>
```

I am trying to get the value of response_phone by this:

```
$(xml).find('response_phone').text()
```

What it returns is:

```
"    johndoe    "
```

Any ideas why does this happen and how to get it right? I can't change the XML as it comes from a server. Thanks.

Comment: looks fine to me http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/edymL/

Comment: Funny. Not for me. Actually I am using AppMobi and try to parse this xml as retrieved from the server with an $.ajax() call.

Comment: can you share the ajax request

Comment: I now tried your solution. If I read the responseText in the complete event, it returns an empty string as expected. Reading the XML in the success event produces the error. Anyway, here is the code.

http://pastebin.com/jtCwBU8Q

Comment: look at http://plnkr.co/edit/m2GpC6z5QMJK3OtxQ5K1?p=preview also it seems to be working

Comment: Then it might be an AppMobi glitch, not a general JQuery bug.

Comment: haven't used AppMobi... so not sure

Comment: Well, at least we found a way to get around this bug. Thanks a lot, guys!

Comment: how are you going to fix it

Comment: I'll use the complete event instead of success.